# How can I aggregate two classes of values in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have a table that contains intervals:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    user_id: INTEGER,
    start: TIMESTAMP,
    end: TIMESTAMP,
    billable: BOOLEAN
);
```

I want to create a view that looks like this:

```
user_id | billable_time | unbillable_time
```

I can get *one* of these two using a query like this:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(end - start) AS billable_time WHERE billable = TRUE GROUP BY user_id;
```

However, I need both columns, with unbillable time being the equivalent:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(end - start) AS unbillable_time WHERE billable = FALSE GROUP BY user_id;
```

How can I get those two values into one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select user_id, sum(case billable when 1 then (end - start) end) as can_bill,
  sum(case billable when 0 then (end - start) end) as unbillable
```

Comment: That gives me this error: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 1: ...(CASE billable WHEN TRUE THEN ended - started END CASE) AS p...

Comment: All you have to do is change `end case` to `end` and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, I used MySQL stored procedure syntax by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, billable, sum(end - start) AS billable_time 
GROUP BY user_id,billable;
```

Comment: That's not at all what I was looking for.  I thought it was obvious, but I suppose I'd better clear up the question.

Comment: it's faster and easier to do the presentation in the application layer. My other answer will give you the layout you want at the expense of speed.

Comment: I agree.  However, I've been told "Put it in the database"

So, it's either this, or a cron job to update a table with the same structure.  Faugh.